# How to send post request to a api using php with static ip address

Tags: php

I want to make an API call with my static IP address using PHP.
I want help that how I send API requests with a static IP address. I googled it and tried the solution but it did not work well.

```
<?php
$myIP = "119.18.49.57";
$curl = curl_init();<br>
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => 'link',
                            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                            CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
                            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
                            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
                            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
                            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
                            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
                            CURLOPT_INTERFACE=> $myIP,
                            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => ',
                            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("REMOTE_ADDR: $myIP", "X_FORWARDED_FOR: $myIP"))
                        ));
                      echo  $response = curl_exec($curl);
                        curl_close($curl);
                        ?>
```

I have tried the above code.
I am getting errors from the organisation's end. They are telling it is because of IP address.

Comment: How did it not work well? Please [edit] your post and add a description of any error messages, etc, you saw.